# Construct an additive group by transfinite induction

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

I know one way to construct a Bernstein set that is an additive group.Here is the way that I know. $\{P_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ all nonempty perfect subsets of $\Bbb R.$ Choose, by recursion on $\xi<\mathfrak c$, sequence $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ and $\{y_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ so that $$ x_\xi,y_\xi\in P_\xi\setminus\Bbb Q\bigg(\{x_\zeta\colon \zeta<\xi\}\cup \{y_\zeta\colon \zeta<\xi\}\bigg ).$$ This choice can be made since

$$\Bigg|\Bbb Q\bigg(\{x_\zeta\colon \zeta<\xi\}\cup\{y_\zeta\colon \zeta<\xi\}\bigg)\Bigg|<\mathfrak c$$
Now we define $B=\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}.$ Notice that $ B$ is Bernstein set. In addition, $B$ is linear independent over $\mathbb Q.$

Next, let $B_1$ be linear space generated by $B.$ So, $B_1$ is as needed, that for any perfect $P\subset\mathbb R$ we have $$P\cap B_1\neq\emptyset\ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ P\setminus B_1\neq\emptyset$$

Indeed, $B_1\cap P\neq\emptyset$ since $B$ does so. Consider the quotient group $\mathbb R\setminus B_1,$ for contradiction, assume $P\subset B_1.$ Now, let $x+B_1$ be a nonzero coset and where $x\notin B_1$ so $x+P\subset x+B_1.$ Notice that $x+P$ is a perfect set and $(x+P)\cap B_1=\emptyset$  which is a contradiction.

I was wondering if there is another way to construct $B_1.$ I hope from those that have a deep understanding  and more knowledge to share their ideas. So, student like me they will get  a lot of benefits from that. Any hint or help  will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Killer typo: In the 2 displayed lines the 1st 4 of the 5 instances of $\mathfrak c$ should be $\xi.$ Also: $B$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q,$ not over $\mathfrak c.$

Comment: How do you prove that no $P_{\xi}$ is a subset of $B$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I fixed and added more details. Is it clear now?

Comment: My edit was for a typo: cost... coset. It's clear. BTW since $B\cup \{y_{\xi}:\xi<c\}$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q,$ no $y_{\xi}$ is in $ B_1$ so $P_{\xi}\not\subset B_1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I am just curious, do you know another way to construct  a Bernstein set that is an additive group.

Comment: I have an idea but I dk if it will work. I need a little time.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Take your time. Thank you.

Comment: I have posted my idea as a Q as I dk whether it works https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992491/is-this-additive-subgroup-of-bbb-r-a-bernstein-set

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, appreciated it. I checked and I commented in it

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As my answer to that question shows, it will not work as a "blackbox" - at least some (and possibly all) Hamel bases will yield non-Bernstein sets.

Comment: Yes I understood the A.