# Is this additive subgroup of $\Bbb R$ a Bernstein set?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

This Q [Construct an additive group by transfinite induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983985/construct-an-additive-group-by-transfinite-induction?noredirect=1#comment8228285_3983985) asked for proof-verification and also asked for other ways to construct a Bernstein subset of $\Bbb R$ that is also an additive group.

Consider $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over the field $\Bbb Q$ and let $B$ be a Hamel basis for $\Bbb R$ with $1\in B.$ For each $x\in \Bbb R$ there is a unique $\{x_b:b\in B\}\subset \Bbb Q$ such that $x=\sum_{b\in B}bx_b.$ ( Only finitely many $x_b$ are non-$0$.).

Q: Is the additive group  $S=\{x\in \Bbb R: x_1\in \Bbb Z\}$ a Bernstein set?

The set $S\cap [0,1)$ is an old textbook example of a non-Lebesgue-measurable set and it has inner Lebesgue measure $0.$ But does $S$ have an uncountable closed Lebesgue-null subset? I have not got anywhere on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is at least *possible* for $S$ to have a perfect subset (which is by definition uncountable and closed, and must be null since $S$ has inner measure $0$). I suspect some $B$s will yield Bernstein $S$s, though I haven't verified that.

---

Consider the following result (where $\{q_w: w\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is some fixed enumeration of the rationals):

> Fix a natural number $k$ and finitely many disjoint nondegenerate closed intervals $A_1,...,A_n$ with $1\in A_1$. There are disjoint nondegenerate closed intervals $B_1,...,B_{2n}$ such that $1\in B_1$ and for each $i\in\{1,...,2n\}$ we have:
>
> - $B_{2i}\cup B_{2i+1}\subseteq A_i$, and
> - for each $f\in B_i$ and each $g_1,...,g_k\in \bigcup_{j\in\{1,...,2n\}\setminus\{i\}}B_j$, there are no $c_1,...,c_k\in \{q_1,...,q_k\}\cup\{0\}$ such that $$f=\sum_{u=1}^kc_ug_u.$$

The proof is straightforward but tedious. The point is that by iterating this - increasing $k$ as we go along - we get a Cantor-set-like construction of a perfect $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly-independent set $Y$ with $1\in Y$; by cutting out a small open neighborhood of $1$, we get a $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly-independent perfect set $X$ whose span doesn't contain $1$. But now if we take a Hamel basis $B\supseteq Y$ (by Zorn), we get that $X$ is a perfect subset of the corresponding $S$.

Comment: +1. So far so good. I rarely post Q's.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I do not understand your definition of $S$. Since there is  $x_1$  and $\Bbb Z$. So, $S$ will just $Bbb Z$

Comment: @00GB. $x_1$ is the "first" co-ordinate of the vector $x$ with respect to the basis $B$. . Since the field of the vector space is $\Bbb Q$, the co-ordinate $x_1$ will belong to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @00GB Remember that "$x_b$" (for $b\in B$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$) is the coefficient of $b$ in the unique representation of $x$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of elements of the Hamel basis $B$ (recall that we have $1\in B$, so $x_1$ actually makes sense). The OP's $S$ can be redefined as the set of reals which differ from some linear combination of elements of $B\setminus\{1\}$ by an integer.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Incidentally, is there a problem with working with $S_0=\{x: x_1=0\}$ instead?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, why $S$ is a Bernstein set

Comment: @00GB The point of my answer is that it shows that there is a $B$ whose associated $S$ is **not** a Bernstein set (since it contains a perfect set). As I say at the end, I suspect that some $B$s do have their corresponding $S$s be Bernstein but I haven't checked that. The point is that this contrasts with the situation mentioned in the OP with respect to measure, where **every** $B$ yields an $S$ with a particular measure-theoretic property (namely, being non-measurable and having inner measure zero).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, have you checked your $S_0$

Comment: @00GB I'm not sure what you mean. We have $S_0\subseteq S$ always (by definition) and in my example $S_0$ contains a perfect set already, so the situation is the same. My question to Daniel was based on what *he* wanted: depending on his interest in $S$, it might be easier to work with $S_0$ instead. (Note that like $S$, the set $S_0$ is an additive group as well since we always have $x_1+y_1=(x+y)_1$ and $0+0=0$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Thank you.  I am still to construct such Bernstein set if I could I will definitely post it

Comment: I don't see any immediate problem with working with $S_0$ instead.